# How to save the value of a html element into a javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a calculator and I would like to take the current value of the p element, save it into a var, and use document.getElementById to change the contents of the p element. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/GuardianWolfe/stzhfnLm/1/. I currently using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plusButton").click(function () {
        var eqVal = document.getElementById("equation").value;
        document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = eqVal + " +";
    });
});
```

But it does not do anything.

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery in the fiddle; try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stzhfnLm/5/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems,

1, P tag doesnt have the value property, You should use `innerHTML` to get the value,

2, Your fiddle doesnt have jquery refered, So the error will happen at `$(document).ready(`

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/stzhfnLm/9/)

If you want to done the things with jquery only use like this

```
$("#plusButton").click(function() {
    var eqVal = $("#equation").text();
    $("#equation").text(eqVal + "Hei");
});
```

[**Fiddle for jquery code**](http://jsfiddle.net/stzhfnLm/7/)

Comment: +1 but sounds like OP would like to make some maths operations, not concatening string. I guess OP's next question ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff Most probably. Expecting that, OP will edit the question regarding the new requirements. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

First off, jQuery isn't included in your JSFiddle demo. You can include this through the *Frameworks & Extensions* area in the sidebar on the left. Your code is initially throwing the following error because of this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Secondly, your element with ID `equation` is a `p` element. `p` elements do not have a `value` property. You can get the text of your `p` element using `innerHTML` instead:

```
var eqVal = document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML;
```

Thirdly, you're already using jQuery so why are you not using jQuery for the above?

```
var eqVal = $('#equation').text();
// Or
var eqVal = $('#equation').html();
```

Finally, you can update the value using jQuery as well:

```
$('#equation').html(eqVal + " +");
```

[**Amended JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/stzhfnLm/8/).

Comment: `.innerText` is only for IE browsers, btw; `.text()` would be fine too :)

Comment: @Jack Chrome too. Apparently Firefox is the only browser which doesn't support it. I've modified my answer regardless.

Comment: Yeah, for that reason I typically end up with `n.textContent || n.innerText || ''` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can make it simple like this

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/stzhfnLm/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plusButton").click(function () {
        var eqVal = $('#equation').text();
        $('#equation').html(eqVal + "Hei");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, load JQuery in your code.

Then, Change your code, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#plusButton").click(function () {

        var eqVal = $("#equation").html();  // Get value of p tag
        $("#equation").html() = eqVal + " +";  // Set value 
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure about this solution?